# Limit $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want evaluate this $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\dfrac{xy^3}{x^2+y^4}$. I tried polar coordinates and I got this $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{r^2\cos\theta \sin^3\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}$$

I would like to show that $\dfrac{\cos\theta \sin^3\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}$ is bounded, but I was not able to do that. Any hint?

Comment: Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232125/limits-displaystyle-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-fracxy2x2-y2?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534100/lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-dfracxy2x2-y2?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441964/undersetx-y-rightarrow-0-0-textlim-fracxyy-x3?rq=1).

Answer (score 3):

We have $(|x|-y^2)^2\geq 0$, hence $2|x|y^2\leq (x^2+y^4)$. So if $f(x,y)$ is your function we have for $(x,y)\not =(0,0)$ the inequality:
$$2|f(x,y)|=|y|\frac{2|x|y^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq |y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
and it is easy to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix $\theta$ and take $r\rightarrow 0$.

\begin{eqnarray}
lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{c_\theta s^3_\theta}{c_\theta^2 +r^2s^4_\theta}&=&\frac{c_\theta s^3_\theta}{c_\theta^2} \\
&=& \frac{s^3_\theta}{c_\theta}
\end{eqnarray}

We see that this depends on $\theta$ and is not bounded, for example when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, this does not fully answer the original question since for any nonzero $r$ the quantity considered 0.

Let us consider $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon$, and we will take $r\rightarrow 0$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{s^3_\theta}{c_\theta} &=& \frac{1-\epsilon^2}{-\epsilon}
\end{eqnarray}
This is clearly unbounded as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: You are forgetting the $r^2$ in the numerator!

Comment: Ah, I was working with what the OP put in the second half of his question. If that is incorrect, then yes, so is the above.